# Tool to generate mapper classes from service reference

Tags: c#, web-services

I have couple of WSDLs to refer from my project.

For the decoupling concerns I need to map the classes defined in service reference to my own classes.
Is there is any way or tool to generate these mapper classes instead of copy pasting?

Comment: This is really good question, unfortunately, it's off-topic. Also, it's a little bit vague. What do you mean in mapping? Copying value from one object (service object here) to another (your already existed class) or auto-generating classes which have the same properties as wsdl class? If the first one is the case, than automapper should work fine.

Comment: I'll have a mapping layer and I will map the service object to an object in my control.So far I'm creating individual classes by looking at the service reference.My question is can I automate this class creation process?

Comment: So your question is about autocreating classes. In that case you should go with @p.s.w.g's solution. However, attentively read commends that are left on that answer.

Comment: did you tried AutoMapper ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) is a convention-based mapping tool with a fluent API. It's specifically designed to handle mapping concerns in situations like this.

I've used it on a number of projects and been very happy with it.

Comment: Well I'm also using AutoMapper in my mapping layer.But can I use it to create Individual classes to map to the Service Reference?

Comment: @PAVITRA Sorry, I think I misunderstood the question. To be sure I understand - are you looking for something to generate domain objects that AutoMapper will use as the target of a mapping operation, with the classes defined by WSDL to be used as the source?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Web Services Description Language Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx) to generate the C# classes needed to interact with the web service.

```
wsdl /out:myProxyClass.cs http://host/WebService.asmx?WSDL
```

Or you can use the newer [ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx):

```
svcutil /t:code http://host/WebService.svc /out:myProxyClass.cs /config:myProxyClass.config
```

If necessary you can then modify these classes yourself.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to modify auto-generated classes, they are partial. Modifying, auto-generated files is always the least thing you should do because it can be regenerated and all modifications will be lost.

Comment: @Leri If they are auto-generated by your IDE or some other component in your build process, I totally agree. However, I think OP is looking to just generate some boilerplate code, and then tweak it as needed. Then it would probably only be needed once. Even in that case, though, I agree with you. If possible, it's better to only extend it through partial classes.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Still that wont generate mapper classes with getters,setters and all right? What I get is the generated proxy class.My requirement is to generate mapping classes to that proxy class.

Comment: @PAVITRA I may have misunderstood the requirement. If you just have one set of classes that you'd like to map to another, then AutoMapper, as *RickLiddle* suggests is a good way to go. If you're looking to create custom classes that are based on types defined in a WSDL, and which can be used directly when making web service calls, then wsdl.exe and svcutil.exe are good solutions.